# how to extract data from different urls inside a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract company reviews from Seek.com. The issue I am facing is that when I'm trying to extract the title of the review, after 2-3 titles it gives an error message and every time it generates a different error message. 
The code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://www.seek.com.au/companies/telstra-432298/reviews')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'data-automation' :'reviewCard'})
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]
# print(hrefs)

with open('title.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow("title")
    for href in hrefs:
        print("something")
        pages= requests.get('https://www.seek.com.au' + href)
        soup2= BeautifulSoup(pages.text, 'html.parser')
        title = soup2.find_all(class_='_3FrNV7v HfVIlOd E6m4BZb')
        csv_writer.writerow(title)
```

I cant figure out how to extract only the information from the page and why the error is popping up again and again.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: every time I get a different error. so sometimes it gives " _csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType", sometimes it gives no error and no output

Comment: Running it, for me, `links` is always an empty list

Comment: the url in your example does not show any result. Probably seek does not work that way

Comment: I was able to get a list of urls in hrefs. The problem is it gives different results everytime.

Comment: data are rendered by JS, you should use selenium to get what you want

Comment: I tried doing normal extraction but since each panel is a link to a different page where the complete text is given hence I need to iterate over urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Selenium or iterate through the urls. It's all there through the api. All you need to do is figure out how many reviews there are so you'll know how many pages to iterate through (you get a max number of 1000 reviews per page returned in json).

Then just use pandas to dump into a dataframe and write straight to disk.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests
import math

request_url = 'https://company-profiles-api.cloud.seek.com.au/v1/companies/432298/reviews'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'}


# Get the total number of reviews to calculate how many pages to iterate through
payload = {
'page': '1',
'perPage': '1000'}

data = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
total_reviews = data['paging']['total']
total_pages = math.ceil(total_reviews / 1000)

# Initialize a dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate through pages and append to results dataframe
for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    payload = {
            'page': '%s' %page,
            'perPage': '1000'}

    data = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    temp_df = json_normalize(data['data'])

    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

results.to_csv('title.csv', index=False)
```

**Results:**

```
print (results.head(10).to_string())
  companyName  companyRecommended                                               cons  crowdflowerScore       id  isAnonymized                                jobTitle  normalizedCfScore                                               pros  ratingBenefitsAndPerks  ratingCareerOpportunity  ratingCompanyOverall  ratingDiversity  ratingExecutiveManagement ratingStressLevel  ratingWorkEnvironment  ratingWorkLifeBalance       reviewCreatedAt reviewCreatedTimeAgoText reviewResponse reviewResponseBy reviewResponseCreatedAt reviewResponseCreatedTimeAgoText reviewResponseForeignUserId  roleProximityScore salarySummary salarySummaryDisplayText     score timeAgoText                                              title              workLocation         yearLeft yearLeftEmploymentStatusText yearsWorkedWith yearsWorkedWithText
0     Telstra                True  Layers of inefficient  processes and business ...               3.0  5318069         False                          NBN Specialist             2000.0  Good work life balance and great office facili...                       5                        2                     3              4.0                          2              None                      4                      4  2019-07-12T03:27:46Z             2 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002          fair                  Average  3.056594        None  Telstra is a company with great values and the...   Brisbane QLD, Australia        left_2019              former employee       7_8_years        7 to 8 years
1     Telstra                True  The company is currently in a re-structure mod...               3.0  5317669         False                        Business Analyst             2000.0  High daily rate, modern office, my management ...                       5                        5                     3              5.0                          2              None                      3                      5  2019-07-07T20:57:28Z             2 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002      generous                     High  3.056594        None  It's still a great place is work, I've met a g...     Sydney NSW, Australia        left_2019              former employee        0_1_year    Less than 1 year
2     Telstra               False  So many broken process which consume colossal ...               3.0  5316942         False                        Business Analyst             2000.0  You are empowered to deliver and make choices....                       1                        1                     3              5.0                          2              None                      2                      5  2019-06-28T02:34:04Z             2 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002         below                      Low  3.056594        None  The learning curve has been very steep for me ...  Melbourne VIC, Australia  still_work_here             current employee       3_4_years        3 to 4 years
3     Telstra               False  The company is driven by continuous short term...               3.0  5315055         False                 Senior Network Engineer             2000.0  Great talented people to work with and awesome...                       5                        2                     2              5.0                          1              None                      2                      1  2019-06-15T12:55:27Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002          fair                  Average  3.056594        None  Great place if you are single and starting out...  Melbourne VIC, Australia        left_2019              former employee  12_years_above       Over 12 years
4     Telstra                True                 Very hierarchal, too much red tape               3.0  5304650         False                       Account Executive             2000.0  Great opportunities to work anywhere in Austra...                       5                        5                     4              5.0                          4              None                      4                      3  2019-05-07T08:02:40Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002      generous                     High  3.056594        None                       Great flexible working tools     Cairns QLD, Australia        left_2017              former employee      9_10_years       9 to 10 years
5     Telstra                True  Highly regulated environment and working towar...               3.0  5303808         False                      Operations Support             2000.0  Great career development. You get rewarded for...                       5                        5                     4              5.0                          4              None                      4                      4  2019-05-07T02:21:06Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002          fair                  Average  3.056594        None  Would definitely recommend Telstra to a friend...    Adelaide SA, Australia             None              former employee            None                None
6     Telstra                True  Personal development for non IT/Engineering/no...               3.0  5307953         False                      Program Management             2000.0  I have thoroughly enjoyed working with Telstra...                       3                        3                     4              4.0                          4              None                      5                      5  2019-05-07T02:04:42Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002          fair                  Average  3.056594        None  Great people, great work and progressive think...                 Australia             None              former employee            None                None
7     Telstra               False  Executive would not make a decision on whether...               3.0  5307425         False  Senior Customer Service Representative             2000.0  Opportunities were available outside the work ...                       2                        4                     3              4.0                          3              None                      3                      3  2019-05-06T13:43:00Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002         below                      Low  3.056594        None                              Can't trust corporate       Perth WA, Australia        left_2015              former employee       1_2_years        1 to 2 years
8     Telstra               False  Current restructuring is so demoralising and m...               3.0  5299777         False                   Customer Service Role             2000.0  Opportunity to work in any job regardless of w...                       2                        2                     2              4.0                          1              None                      2                      2  2019-05-06T10:26:29Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002          fair                  Average  3.056594        None  Working through the restructure and trying to ...     Sydney NSW, Australia        left_2018              former employee       3_4_years        3 to 4 years
9     Telstra                True  Clients/customers. They need your attention wh...               3.0  5298991         False                        Sales Consultant             2000.0  Enjoyed working with a tight team. Programs be...                       4                        3                     4              5.0                          5              None                      5                      2  2019-05-06T09:31:18Z             3 months ago                                                    None                                                         None               0.002          fair                  Average  3.056594        None        Would do it all over again in a heartbeat.    Brisbane QLD, Australia        left_2018              former employee       1_2_years        1 to 2 years
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it doesn't retrieve the full text. To get the full text, I need to navigate to the URL of that review and then extract the text from there

Comment: what "full text" are you referring to?

Comment: sorry! I had a misunderstanding. it works fine. Could you please explain the approach used here ? where can I find this api ?

Comment: I found that this method only works for this website, not all websites have an api to get data from directly. the other websites I tried was glassdoor and indeed

Comment: That is correct. Every website is different, and will require different specifications. As I stated in our email exchange,  this doesn't ALWAYS work, but it's one of the things I always check. When there is no API, the next thing I try is to see if the data is within `<script>` tags in the html source. If that doesn't seem to work, I then try to automate a browser (with Selenium), to let the page render, then usually you could grab the data as you normally would.